# How to load objects through VBO method in Symbian^3?

Tags: opengl, 3d, symbian

I am currently developing a 3D action game on Symbian^3 platform. So far I am using 289 objects in my game application. I have loaded all of these objects through index vertex array method. But as project grows in size its performance on device decreases(in terms of speed and smoothness).

Is there any limit on maximum no of objects we can use in Symbian^3?

Now I want to load my objects through VBO method in order to increase performance. Is there any example for object loading through VBO method in Symbian^3?

Please suggest me regarding this. Thanks in advance.

Atul Prakash Singh

Comment: This question is vague. What is an "object"? Is using VBOs on Symbian different from any other OpenGL ES implementation?

Answer (score 1):

Placing each and every mesh in it's own VBO will have some performance hit, since switching VBOs is not for free. Instead I recommend sharing a VBO between several meshes. Then instead of switching the VBO you set the offset into the VBO to where the mesh begins in the VBO by supplying the right pointer/offset to `gl{Vertex,VertexAttrib,Color,Normal,TexCoord}Pointer`.